# Backbone example app and javascript apply

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hi can someone explain why in backbone example app (http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html) in **remaining()** function, is called using apply (*this.without.apply(this, this.done());*) and not *this.without(this.done())*

```
 // Filter down the list of all todo items that are finished.
done: function() {
  return this.where({done: true});
},

// Filter down the list to only todo items that are still not finished.
remaining: function() {
  return this.without.apply(this, this.done());
},
```

Thank You !

**#Update**

Debugger output

```
this.without(this.done())
[child, child, child, child]
this.without.apply(this, this.done());
[child, child, child]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Variable list of arguments

The key is in the way without is written:

```
function () {
  var args = slice.call(arguments);
  args.unshift(this.models);
  return _[method].apply(_, args);
}
```

It's anticipating a variable list of arguments, and one way to do that is to use apply:

```
...
return this.without.apply(this, ['pass', 'these', 'arguments']);
```

There's more about apply in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 2):

You asked what is the difference between these two calls:

```
this.without( this.done() )
```

vs.

```
this.without.apply( this, this.done() );
```

To clarify, let's remove the nested `this.done()` call. Now the first one is:

```
var value = this.done();
this.without( value );
```

That code obviously calls `this.without()` and passes it a single argument, whatever `value` was returned by `this.done()`. If `value` happens to be an array, the entire array is passed as a single argument.

The second version becomes:

```
var array = this.done();
this.without.apply( this, array );
```

That calls `this.without()` with a variable number of arguments, one argument for each element of `array`. (And I called it `array` instead of `value` this time, because for this code to make sense it has to be an array.)

`.apply()` also sets `this` in the called function, so passing `this` as the first argument just passes `this` along to that function in the same manner as a regular `this.without()` method call.

Answer (score 0):

apply also lets you specify the "this" object for the function.
That matters sometimes, like when it is being called in a closure, where "this" might be different than you intended.